# How to remove duplicate entry sorted on property name, with latest date

Tags: powershell, sorting, duplicates

I'm trying to remove a duplicate entry from a variable, without any luck

I tried using -Unique, but cant figure out how to narrow it down to not filter out the entry with the latest sourcedate

Result is:

[image]

I want to filter out all duplicates based on name, but sorted on sourcedate

```
Get-CMPackage -Fast | Where-Object {$_.Manufacturer -like "Lenovo"  -and $_.Name -like "*Drivers*"}  | 
Sort-Object -Property SourceDate -Unique | Select-Object PackageID,Name,SourceDate
```

Comment: What happens if you `Sort-Object -Property SourceDate -Descending -Unique`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a double sort.

```
Get-CMPackage -Fast |
    Where-Object {$_.Manufacturer -like "Lenovo"  -and $_.Name -like "*Drivers*"} | 
       Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique | 
          Sort-Object -Property SourceDate | 
              Select-Object PackageID,Name,SourceDate
```

`Group-Object` could also be used.

```
Get-CMPackage -Fast |
    Where-Object {$_.Manufacturer -like "Lenovo"  -and $_.Name -like "*Drivers*"} | 
       Group-Object -Property Name | 
           Select-Object @{n='PackageID';e={$_.group.PackageID}},
                         Name,
                         @{n='SourceDate';e={($_.group.SourceDate | Sort-Object)[0]}}
```

Comment: Hi, this filters out the T460s package with the latest date (07-07-2019), I want it to be reversed, how can that be archived ?

Comment: This is working :  

`Get-CMPackage -Fast |
    Where-Object {$_.Manufacturer -like "Lenovo"  -and $_.Name -like "*Drivers*"} | 
       Sort-Object -Property SourceDate -Descending | 
          Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique | 
              Select-Object PackageID,Name,SourceDate`  
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I forget where I got this from - and it might be overkill for your purposes - but posting it here in case you/anyone else finds it useful.

This function selects items based on a property only where each property member is unique.

```
function Select-Unique
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string[]] $Property,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $InputObject,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $AsHashtable,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $NoElement
    )

    begin
    {
        $Keys = @{}
    }

    process
    {
        $InputObject | foreach-object {

            $o = $_
            $k = $Property | foreach-object -begin {
                    $s = ''
                } -process {
                    # Delimit multiple properties like group-object does.
                    if ( $s.Length -gt 0 )
                    {
                        $s += ', '
                    }

                    $s += $o.$_ -as [string]
                } -end {
                    $s
                }

            if ( -not $Keys.ContainsKey($k) )
            {
                $Keys.Add($k, $null)
                if ( -not $AsHashtable )
                {
                    $o
                }
                elseif ( -not $NoElement )
                {
                    $Keys[$k] = $o
                }
            }
        }
    }

    end
    {
        if ( $AsHashtable )
        {
            $Keys
        }
    }
}
```